how to give background color to the Jtree , DefaultTreeCellRenderer using java swing
I have a created a following renderer which renders the JTree with icon and folder list.
I want to add different color to the background of that section. i tried giving it to panel but the Jtree is above left panel so it's not getting applied. How do I do it? Please help me. Thank you in advance.
here is ss of where i want grey background color
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/OlO9Y7J1.png
glance of code where i need to change
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
            private final ImageIcon mainFolderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(strings.getString("folder_icon")));
            private final ImageIcon folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(strings.getString("folder_icon")));

            // Scale the image to the desired size
            ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(strings.getString("right_arrow_icon")));
            int width = 20;  // Width in pixels
            int height = 20; // Height in pixels
            // Scale the image to the desired size
            Image scaledImage = originalIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            // Create a new ImageIcon with the scaled image
            ImageIcon arrowIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);

            private final int VERTICAL_GAP = 5; // Adjust this value as needed

            @Override
            public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
                label.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 14)); // Increase font size of file name

                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                boolean isMainFolder = (node.getParent() == null);
 // Set the custom cell renderer for the tree
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        // Add a tree selection listener to handle folder selections
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                // Get the selected node
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

                // Check if it is a folder node
                if (selectedNode != null && selectedNode.isLeaf()) {
                    // Perform the desired action for folder selection
                    String folderName = selectedNode.getUserObject().toString();
                    int position = selectedNode.getParent().getIndex(selectedNode);
                    System.out.println("Folder selected: " + folderName);
                    System.out.println("Position: " + position);
                    DriveFile driveFile1 = folderLeftList.get(position);
                    if (!breadcrumbTrail.contains(driveFile1)) {
                        breadcrumbTrail.add(driveFile1);
                    }

                    // Create a new renderer component with white text color
                    DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) tree.getCellRenderer();
                    JLabel label = (JLabel) renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, selectedNode, false, false, true, position, false);
                    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    // Repaint the tree to update the text color
                    tree.repaint();

                    new FileManagerController(drive, username, role, context, cookieStore, dashboardView, listDriveNames, 23, driveFile1, fileManagerView, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, password, null, 0, null, null, mapDrives, null, null, loginForm, null, null, null, isListView, null);
                }
            }
        });

        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // Set the desired background color
        leftPanel.setBorder(null); // Removes any border set on the panel
        leftPanel.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);



A renderer’s job is only to render the content of a cell.  To make the color vary depending on whether the cell is selected, use the boolean sel argument passed to the getTreeCellRendererComponent.  You must not call tree.setCellRenderer from within your renderer class.  You must not call tree.addTreeSelectionListener from within your renderer class.

Do you know about the look-and-feel? List of keys is here.
